# PHP Zend Compare form field value with constant

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I want to make a form with a password field. I want to compare the password field with a constant. Is it possible to do with `addValidator()`?

```
$this->addElement( $this->createElement ( 'password', 'password' )
                        ->setAttrib('class','fld')
                        ->setLabel ( 'Slaptažodis: ' )
                        ->addValidator('Identical',
                                       false,
                                       array('token' => 'value')
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
    $constantHere = '123';
    $this->addElement( $this->createElement ( 'password', 'password' )
                    ->setAttrib('class','fld')
                    ->setLabel ( 'Slaptažodis: ' )
                    ->addValidator('Identical',
                                   false,
                                   $constantHere));
```

you only use Array with TOKEN when u wanna compare with another element, if you wanna compare with constant u need use directly in the last argument.

see more here: 
[zend doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#zend-validator-set-identical-types)